# TeamCity web interface not accessible on Chrome

Tags: teamcity

I've installed teamcity on two machines now. The first, I tried reinstalling multiple times because the web interface would launch in Chrome and fail with:

> This site can’t be reached The webpage at http://localhost:6666/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>
> ERR_UNSAFE_PORT

The teamcity-server service was running, but not accessible on the port I'd set up. Eventually I tried `curl localhost:6666`, and got a response, so tried again in Edge browser. In Edge, everything works fine.

On the second machine, same deal. Installed fine, not found in Chrome, works fine in Edge.

Is this a known issue with TeamCity? Is there some kind of setting in Chrome that may need changing? How should I go about diagnosing and fixing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that port 6666 is considered unsafe by Chrome (hence the `ERR_UNSAFE_PORT` error), as it clashes with one used by Alternate IRC [Apple addition].

I looked into this and found a list of [ports to avoid](https://superuser.com/a/188070/178675), so as to avoid having to modify the Chrome shortcut as recommended by @Wesley Rolnick.

```
1,       // tcpmux
7,       // echo
9,       // discard
11,      // systat
13,      // daytime
15,      // netstat
17,      // qotd
19,      // chargen
20,      // ftp data
21,      // ftp access
22,      // ssh
23,      // telnet
25,      // smtp
37,      // time
42,      // name
43,      // nicname
53,      // domain
77,      // priv-rjs
79,      // finger
87,      // ttylink
95,      // supdup
101,     // hostriame
102,     // iso-tsap
103,     // gppitnp
104,     // acr-nema
109,     // pop2
110,     // pop3
111,     // sunrpc
113,     // auth
115,     // sftp
117,     // uucp-path
119,     // nntp
123,     // NTP
135,     // loc-srv /epmap
139,     // netbios
143,     // imap2
179,     // BGP
389,     // ldap
427,     // SLP (Also used by Apple Filing Protocol)
465,     // smtp+ssl
512,     // print / exec
513,     // login
514,     // shell
515,     // printer
526,     // tempo
530,     // courier
531,     // chat
532,     // netnews
540,     // uucp
548,     // AFP (Apple Filing Protocol)
556,     // remotefs
563,     // nntp+ssl
587,     // stmp?
601,     // ??
636,     // ldap+ssl
993,     // ldap+ssl
995,     // pop3+ssl
2049,    // nfs
3659,    // apple-sasl / PasswordServer
4045,    // lockd
6000,    // X11
6665,    // Alternate IRC [Apple addition]
6666,    // Alternate IRC [Apple addition]
6667,    // Standard IRC [Apple addition]
6668,    // Alternate IRC [Apple addition]
6669,    // Alternate IRC [Apple addition]
6697,    // IRC + TLS
```

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to explicitly allow that port.  From the guide [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/err_unsafe_port-error-on-google-chrome):

You can modify the shortcut to Chrome so that it explicitly allows that port when chrome launches:  `"C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --explicitly-allowed-ports=6666"`